# Parametric - a simple program argument parser

Tags: c++, parsing, console

I've made a little header-only library for handling user input for console applications, I'd really appreciate it if you guys took a short look at it and told me what you think. The goal of the library is to provide a simple and quick way of setting up programs with a usable CL interface.

My repository (including a basic usage guide) can be found [here](https://github.com/Goubermouche/parametric/).

```
// Parametric: a basic and simple program options parser.
// Made by: @Goubermouche (https://github.com/Goubermouche)

// Copyright(c) 2024 Goubermouche
// 
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files(the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and /or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions :
// 
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
// copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
// SOFTWARE.

#pragma once

#include <filesystem>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <format>
#include <any>
#include <map>

#define PARAMETRIC_TABLE_WIDTH 60

namespace parametric {
    constexpr inline int ERROR_RESULT = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    // default option parser overloads: 

    template<typename type>
    struct options_parser {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> type {
            return value;
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<float> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> float {
            return std::stof(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<double> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> double {
            return std::stof(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<bool> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            if(value == "true") {
                return true;
            }

            if(value == "false") {
                return false;
            }

            return static_cast<bool>(std::stoul(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint8_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint8_t {
            return static_cast<uint8_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint16_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint16_t {
            return static_cast<uint16_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint32_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint32_t {
            return std::stoul(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint64_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint64_t {
            return std::stoull(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int8_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int8_t {
            return static_cast<int8_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int16_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int16_t {
            return static_cast<int16_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int32_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int32_t {
            return std::stoi(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int64_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int64_t {
            return std::stoll(value);
        }
    };

    namespace detail {
        /**
         * \brief Checks if the specified \b value is a help flag (--help or -h).
         * \param value Value to check
         * \return True if the specified \b value is a help flag, false otherwise.
         */
        inline auto is_help_flag(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            return value == "--help" || value == "-h";
        }

        /**
         * \brief Prints a block of strings aligned to \b start_offset and limited to a given max width
         * by \b max_width.
         * \param strings Strings to print
         * \param start_offset Start offset to print the strings with
         * \param max_width Max width of each line in the block
         */
        inline void print_aligned_strings(const std::vector<std::string>& strings, std::size_t start_offset, std::size_t max_width) {
            std::size_t current_width = 0;

            for (const auto& string : strings) {
                current_width += string.size();

                if (current_width > max_width) {
                    // print a newline and align to the beginning of the line above
                    std::cout << "\n" << std::string(start_offset, ' ');
                    current_width = string.size();
                }

                std::cout << string;
            }
        }

        /**
         * \brief Checks if a given \b value is a verbose flag (whether it begins with two dashes).
         * \param value Value to check
         * \return True if the specified \b value is a verbose flag, false otherwise.
         */
        inline auto is_verbose_flag(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            // NOTE: this isn't a smart function, but it handles everything correctly for
            //       our needs

            if (value.length() < 2) {
                return false;
            }

            return value[0] == '-' && value[1] == '-';
        }

        /**
         * \brief Checks if a given \b value is a flag (whether it begins with a dash).
         * \param value Value to check
         * \return True if the specified \b value is a flag, false otherwise.
         */
        inline auto is_flag(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            // NOTE: this isn't a smart function, but it handles everything correctly for
            //       our needs

            if (value.empty()) {
                return false;
            }

            return value[0] == '-';
        }

        /**
         * \brief Removes \b up \b to \b two leading dashes from a given string.
         * \param input Input string
         * \param output Output string
         * \return True if the operation succeeded (if we were able to remove at most two dashes),
         * false otherwise (either the string is invalid, or we were able to remove more than two
         * dashes).
         */
        inline auto remove_leading_dashes(const std::string& input, std::string& output) -> bool {
            std::size_t dash_count = 0;

            while (dash_count < input.size() && input[dash_count] == '-') {
                ++dash_count;
            }

            if (dash_count > 2) {
                return false;
            }

            output = input.substr(dash_count);
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * \brief A basic abstraction which allows us to have a map with 1 or 2 keys pointing
         * to the same value.
         * \tparam key_type Type of the two keys
         * \tparam value_type Type of the stored value
         */
        template<typename key_type, typename value_type>
        class dual_map {
            using iterator = typename std::map<key_type, value_type>::iterator;
            using const_iterator = typename std::map<key_type, value_type>::const_iterator;
        public:
            auto insert(const key_type& primary_key, const value_type& value) -> value_type& {
                auto& val_ref = primary_map[primary_key];
                val_ref = value;
                return val_ref;
            }

            auto insert(const key_type& primary_key, const key_type& secondary_key, const value_type& value) -> value_type& {
                auto& val_ref = primary_map[primary_key];
                val_ref = value;
                secondary_to_primary_map[secondary_key] = primary_key;
                return val_ref;
            }

            auto begin() -> iterator { return primary_map.begin(); }
            auto end() -> iterator { return primary_map.end(); }

            auto begin() const -> const_iterator { return primary_map.begin(); }
            auto end() const -> const_iterator { return primary_map.end(); }

            auto cbegin() const -> const_iterator { return primary_map.cbegin(); }
            auto cend() const-> const_iterator { return primary_map.cend(); }

            auto find(const key_type& key) -> iterator {
                auto primary_it = primary_map.find(key);
                if (primary_it != primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_it;
                }

                auto secondary_it = secondary_to_primary_map.find(key);
                if (secondary_it != secondary_to_primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_map.find(secondary_it->second);
                }

                return end();
            }

            auto find(const key_type& key) const -> const_iterator {
                auto primary_it = primary_map.find(key);
                if (primary_it != primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_it;
                }

                auto secondary_it = secondary_to_primary_map.find(key);
                if (secondary_it != secondary_to_primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_map.find(secondary_it->second);
                }

                return end();
            }

            auto empty() const -> bool {
                return primary_map.empty();
            }

            auto size() const -> std::size_t {
                return primary_map.size();
            }
        private:
            std::map<key_type, value_type> primary_map;
            std::unordered_map<key_type, key_type> secondary_to_primary_map;
        };

        // Basic wrappers for erasing the type of our store values

        struct value_wrapper_interface {
            virtual auto parse(const std::string& value) -> std::any = 0;
            virtual ~value_wrapper_interface() = default;

            // used for cases when the value is implicit (ie. pure flags) 
            bool expects_value = true; 
        };

        template<typename type>
        struct value_wrapper : value_wrapper_interface {
            auto parse(const std::string& value) -> std::any override {
                return options_parser<type>::parse(value);
            }
        };

        using value_wrapper_ptr = std::shared_ptr<value_wrapper_interface>;
    } // namespace detail

    /**
     * \brief Pack of parameters which were extracted from userland arguments.
     */
    class parameters {
    public:
        /**
         * \brief Checks whether the parameter pack contains a given key.
         * \param name Key to check
         * \return True if the pack contains the given key, false otherwise
         */
        auto contains(const std::string& name) const -> bool {
            return m_values.contains(name);
        }

        /**
         * \brief Retrieves a given key from the pack.
         * \tparam type Type of the given key
         * \param name Name of the given key
         * \return Value of type \b type held under \b key.
         */
        template<typename type = bool>
        auto get(const std::string& name) const -> type {
            return std::any_cast<type>(m_values.at(name));
        }
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> m_values;

        friend class flag;
        friend class positional_argument;
    };

    /**
     * \brief Context which is passed around when parsing the parameter tree.
     */
    struct context {
        context(int argc, char** argv) : arguments(argv, argv + argc) {
            arguments[0] = std::filesystem::path(argv[0]).filename().string();
        }

        auto can_get_next_value() const -> bool {
            return argument_index + 1 <= arguments.size();
        }

        auto get_next_value() -> const std::string& {
            return arguments[argument_index++];
        }

        void begin_new_scope() {
            m_scoped_argument_index = argument_index;
        }

        /**
         * \brief Creates a string representing all values from \a arguments [0] \a -
         * \a arguments[\a scoped \a argument \a index] separated by a space (' ') char.
         * \return String representation of our argument range.
         */
        auto get_value_string() const -> std::string {
            std::ostringstream oss;

            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_scoped_argument_index && i < arguments.size(); ++i) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    oss << ' ';
                }

                oss << arguments[i];
            }

            return oss.str();
        }

        std::vector<std::string> arguments; // userland arguments

        std::size_t argument_index = 1;            // local argument index used when parsing
        std::size_t positional_argument_index = 0; // index of our positional arguments

        // final output parameters, which are incrementally constructed when parsing
        parameters output_parameters;
    private:
        // helper index which is updated when a new scope (command/command group) is created
        // used for clearer help prints
        std::size_t m_scoped_argument_index = 0;
    };

    /**
     * \brief Represents a simple flag (either --flag or -f). A flag can either implicitly represent
     * a value (when it's declared with a bool type), or a flag which requires a succeeding value.
     * When using a custom type a parametric::options_parser overload for the given type must be
     * defined.
     */
    class flag {
    public:
        flag() = default;
        flag(const std::string& long_name, const std::string& description, const std::string& short_name, const detail::value_wrapper_ptr& value_interface)
            : m_long_name(long_name), m_short_name(short_name), m_description(description), m_value_interface(value_interface) {}
    private:
        auto parse_next(context& context, const std::string& provided_flag_name, const std::string& provided_flag_name_no_dashes) -> int {
            // check dash-correctness
            // since we know our flag has at most two dashes, we don't have to do error checking here
            if (detail::is_flag(provided_flag_name)) {
                const bool is_verbose = detail::is_verbose_flag(provided_flag_name);

                if ((m_long_name == provided_flag_name_no_dashes) != is_verbose) {
                    if (m_short_name.empty()) {
                        // missing long alias
                        std::cout << std::format("error: invalid flag verbosity '{}' (did you mean to use '--{}'?)\n", provided_flag_name, m_long_name);
                    }
                    else {
                        // invalid short/long alias
                        std::cout << std::format("error: invalid flag verbosity '{}' (did you mean to use '-{}' or '--{}'?)\n", provided_flag_name, m_short_name, m_long_name);
                    }

                    return ERROR_RESULT;
                }
            }
            else {
                // not a flag
                std::cout << std::format("error: invalid flag format '{}' (did you mean to use {}?)\n", provided_flag_name, get_label());
                return ERROR_RESULT;
            }

            // parse the final value
            if (m_value_interface->expects_value) {
                if(!context.can_get_next_value()) {
                    std::cout << std::format("error: missing value for flag '{}'\n", provided_flag_name);
                    return ERROR_RESULT;
                }

                const std::string value = context.get_next_value();

                try {
                    context.output_parameters.m_values[m_long_name] = m_value_interface->parse(value);
                }
                catch (...) {
                    std::cout << std::format("error: invalid format for flag '{}'\n", provided_flag_name);
                    return ERROR_RESULT;
                }
            }
            else {
                // pure flag, mark it
                context.output_parameters.m_values[m_long_name] = true;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        auto get_label() const -> std::string {
            if (!m_short_name.empty()) {
                return std::format("[--{} | -{}]", m_long_name, m_short_name);
            }

            return std::format("[--{}]", m_long_name);
        }

        void use_default_if_unused(context& context) const {
            if (!m_default_value.has_value()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!context.output_parameters.contains(m_long_name)) {
                context.output_parameters.m_values[m_long_name] = m_default_value;
            }
        }
    private:
        // info
        std::string m_long_name;
        std::string m_short_name;
        std::string m_description;

        // parse function used when handling value conversions
        detail::value_wrapper_ptr m_value_interface;

        std::any m_default_value; // optional default value

        friend class command;
    };

    /**
     * \brief Represents a simple positional argument. Positional arguments are \b mandatory and
     * should always be specified in a given order. Each argument maps is guaranteed to map to a
     * value in \b parameters. When using a custom type a parametric::options_parser overload for
     * the given type must be defined.
     */
    class positional_argument {
    public:
        positional_argument() = default;
        positional_argument(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, const detail::value_wrapper_ptr& value_interface)
            : m_name(name), m_description(description), m_value_interface(value_interface) {}
    private:
        auto parse_next(context& context) const -> int {
            const std::string value = context.arguments[context.argument_index - 1];

            try {
                context.output_parameters.m_values[m_name] = m_value_interface->parse(value);
            }
            catch (...) {
                std::cout << std::format("error: invalid format for positional argument '{}'\n", m_name);
                return ERROR_RESULT;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    private:
        // info
        std::string m_name; 
        std::string m_description;

        // parse function used when handling value conversions
        detail::value_wrapper_ptr m_value_interface;

        friend class command;
    };

    class command_base {
    public:
        command_base() = default;
        command_base(const std::string& description) : m_description(description) {}

        virtual ~command_base() = default;

    protected:
        virtual void print_help(context& context) = 0;
        virtual auto parse_next(context& context) -> int = 0;
    protected:
        std::string m_description;

        friend class command_group;
    };

    /**
     * \brief Represents a basic command (such as 'add' in 'git add'). Each command is the final unit
     * of logic before userland code is executed. Once a command is run be the user the specified
     * function is executed and the parsed parameters are provided as the parameter.
     */
    class command : public command_base {
    public:
        using function = std::function<int(const parameters&)>;

        command() = default;
        command(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, const function& func)
            : command_base(description), m_name(name), m_function(func) {}

        /**
         * \brief Appends a new flag to the command.
         * \tparam type Type of the flag (defaults to bool, if any other type is specified the flag will
         * also expect a succeeding value to be specified)
         * \param long_name Long flag alias (--flag)
         * \param description Description of the flag
         * \param short_name Short flag alias (-f)
         * \return Reference to the newly created flag.
         */
        template<typename type = bool>
        auto add_flag(const std::string& long_name, const std::string& description, const std::string& short_name = "") -> flag& {
            auto value_interface = std::make_shared<detail::value_wrapper<type>>();

            flag new_flag(long_name, description, short_name, value_interface);

            // handle booleans as flags which don't require a value
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<type, bool>) {
                value_interface->expects_value = false;
                new_flag.m_default_value = false;
            }

            if (!short_name.empty()) {
                return m_flags.insert(long_name, short_name, new_flag);
            }

            return m_flags.insert(long_name, new_flag);
        }

        /**
         * \brief Appends a new flag to the command and assigns its default value.
         * \tparam type Type of the flag (defaults to bool, if any other type is specified the flag will
         * also expect a succeeding value to be specified)
         * \param long_name Long flag alias (--flag)
         * \param description Description of the flag
         * \param short_name Short flag alias (-f)
         * \param default_value Default value which will be used if the flag isn't mentioned by the user
         * \return Reference to the newly created flag.
         */
        template<typename type = bool>
        auto add_flag(const std::string& long_name, const std::string& description, const std::string& short_name, const type& default_value) -> flag& {
            flag& flag = add_flag<type>(long_name, description, short_name);

            // assign the expected value
            flag.m_default_value = default_value;

            return flag;
        }

        /**
         * \brief Appends a new positional argument. Positional arguments need to be specified before any
         * flags, but after commands. \b Positional \b arguments \b are \b mandatory and may not be ignored
         * by the user. The order of individual positional arguments is the same as the order in which the
         * add_positional_argument was called.
         * \tparam type Type the argument should be parsed as
         * \param name Name of the positional argument
         * \param description Description of the positional argument
         */
        template<typename type>
        void add_positional_argument(const std::string& name, const std::string& description) {
            m_arguments.emplace_back(name, description, std::make_shared<detail::value_wrapper<type>>());
        }
    private:
        auto parse_next(context& context) -> int override {
            context.begin_new_scope(); // push a new scope

            // parse all remaining options
            while (context.can_get_next_value()) {
                std::string value = context.get_next_value();

                // if the current key is a help flag
                if (detail::is_help_flag(value)) {
                    print_help(context);
                    return ERROR_RESULT;
                }

                // prefer parsing positional arguments first
                if (context.positional_argument_index < m_arguments.size()) {
                    if (m_arguments[context.positional_argument_index++].parse_next(context) != ERROR_RESULT) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    return ERROR_RESULT; // handled by the parse_next call
                }

                // check against our flag list
                std::string value_no_dashes;

                if (!detail::remove_leading_dashes(value, value_no_dashes)) {
                    // our string has too many dashes, exit
                    std::cout << std::format("error: unknown argument '{}'", value);
                    print_help(context);
                    return ERROR_RESULT;
                }

                // locate the flag
                const auto flag_it = m_flags.find(value_no_dashes);
                if (flag_it != m_flags.end()) {
                    if (flag_it->second.parse_next(context, value, value_no_dashes) != ERROR_RESULT) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    return ERROR_RESULT; // handled by the parse_next call
                }

                std::cout << std::format("error: unknown argument '{}'\n", value);
                print_help(context);
                return ERROR_RESULT;
            }

            // require all positional arguments to be specified
            if (context.positional_argument_index != m_arguments.size()) {
                std::cout << std::format("error: missing positional argument/s for command '{}'\n", m_name);
                print_help(context);
                return ERROR_RESULT;
            }

            // at this point, we've parse_next all of our arguments
            // check against default arguments
            for (const auto& [name, flag] : m_flags) {
                flag.use_default_if_unused(context);
            }

            // run our function
            return m_function(context.output_parameters);
        }

        void print_help(context& context) override {
            const std::string value_string = context.get_value_string();
            std::cout << std::format("usage: {} ", value_string);

            // print a list of available arguments/flags
            std::vector<std::string> labels;
            labels.reserve(m_arguments.size() + m_flags.size());

            for (const auto& arg : m_arguments) {
                labels.emplace_back(std::format("<{}> ", arg.m_name));
            }

            for (const auto& [name, flag] : m_flags) {
                labels.emplace_back(flag.get_label() + " ");
            }

            detail::print_aligned_strings(labels, value_string.size() + 8, PARAMETRIC_TABLE_WIDTH);
            std::cout << "\n";

            // print a description of available arguments/flags
            if (!m_arguments.empty() || !m_flags.empty()) {
                std::cout << '\n';
            }

            // find the longest argument/flag name
            std::size_t longest_name = 0;

            for (const auto& arg : m_arguments) {
                longest_name = std::max(arg.m_name.size(), longest_name);
            }

            for (const auto& [name, flag] : m_flags) {
                longest_name = std::max(name.size(), longest_name);
            }

            // handle arguments
            for (const auto& arg : m_arguments) {
                std::cout << std::format("   {:<{}s}{}\n", arg.m_name, longest_name + 3, arg.m_description);
            }

            if (!m_flags.empty() && !m_arguments.empty()) {
                std::cout << '\n';
            }

            // handle flags
            for (const auto& [name, flag] : m_flags) {
                std::cout << std::format("   {:<{}s}{}\n", name, longest_name + 3, flag.m_description);
            }
        }
    private:
        std::string m_name;  // name of the command
        function m_function; // function to invoke when the command is successfully executed

        detail::dual_map<std::string, flag> m_flags;  // command flags
        std::vector<positional_argument> m_arguments; // list of positional arguments, stored in order of appearances
    };

    /**
     * \brief Grouping of commands, can either hold commands or other command groups. A command
     * group may not be executed on its own and serves only as a wrapper for more commands or
     * command groups.
     */
    class command_group : public command_base {
    public:
        command_group() = default;
        command_group(const std::string& description) : command_base(description) {}

        /**
         * \brief Appends a new child command group.
         * \param name Name of the new command group
         * \param description Description of the new command group
         * \return Reference to the new command group.
         */
        command_group& add_command_group(const std::string& name, const std::string& description) {
            const auto group = std::make_shared<command_group>(description);
            m_commands[name] = group;
            return *group;
        }

        /**
         * \brief Appends a new child command.
         * \param name Name of the new command
         * \param description Description of the new command
         * \param func Function which will be executed if the command is chosen by the user
         * \return Reference to the new command.
         */
        command& add_command(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, const command::function& func) {
            const auto cmd = std::make_shared<command>(name, description, func);
            m_commands[name] = cmd;
            return *cmd;
        }
    protected:
        auto parse_next(context& context) -> int override {
            context.begin_new_scope(); // push a new scope

            // verify that we have a command key
            if (!context.can_get_next_value()) {
                std::cout << "error: missing command\n";
                print_help(context);
                return ERROR_RESULT;
            }

            std::string value = context.get_next_value();

            // if the current key is a help flag
            if (detail::is_help_flag(value)) {
                print_help(context);
                return ERROR_RESULT;
            }

            // look for a command/command group
            const auto command_it = m_commands.find(value);
            if (command_it != m_commands.end()) {
                return command_it->second->parse_next(context);
            }

            std::cout << std::format("error: unknown command '{}'\n", value);
            print_help(context);
            return ERROR_RESULT;
        }

        void print_help(context& context) override {
            const std::string value_string = context.get_value_string();
            std::cout << std::format("usage: {} ", value_string);

            // print a list of available subcommands
            std::vector<std::string> labels;
            labels.reserve(m_commands.size());

            for (const auto& [name, subcommand] : m_commands) {
                labels.emplace_back(std::format("[{}] ", name));
            }

            detail::print_aligned_strings(labels, value_string.size() + 8, PARAMETRIC_TABLE_WIDTH);
            std::cout << "\n\n";

            // find the longest subcommand name
            std::size_t longest_name = 0;

            for (const auto& [name, subcommand] : m_commands) {
                longest_name = std::max(name.size(), longest_name);
            }

            // print all subcommands
            //    name<--padding-->description
            for (const auto& [name, subcommand] : m_commands) {
                std::cout << std::format("   {:<{}s}{}\n", name, longest_name + 3, subcommand->m_description);
            }
        }
    protected:
        std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<command_base>> m_commands; // child commands/command groups
    };

    /**
     * \brief Virtual representation of a program and it's arguments/runtime.
     */
    class program : public command_group {
    public:
        /**
         * \brief Parses the specified program parameters (\b argc, \b argv), and calls the respective function of
         * the chosen command. 
         * \param argc Count of provided arguments
         * \param argv Argument values
         * \return Return code returned by the function of the chosen program. If the help menu is show to the user
         * the program exits with '0'.
         */
        auto parse(int argc, char** argv) -> int {
            context ctx(argc, argv);
            int result = parse_next(ctx);

            // since we don't actually want to return ERROR_RESULT, we override it to '0'
            if (result == ERROR_RESULT) {
                result = 0;
            }

            return result;
        }
    };
} // namespace parametric
```

Answer (score 3):

### Design review

I’ve never seen a command-line parser that treats the command line as a tree, but I think it’s brilliant. It’s one of those things that, now that I’ve seen it, I can’t imagine how I ever saw it any other way.

However, there is are two big problems with this command-line parser library, and the first one is… that it is not actually a command-line parser library. Instead, it is an entire application engine. That’s immediately obvious right from the first basic example:

```
#include <parametric.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    parametric::program program;

    // rat trading
    parametric::command_group& trading = program.add_command_group("trading", "Rat trading");

    // parse and execute the program
    return program.parse(argc, argv);
}
```

See that last comment? “Parse ***and execute*** the program”. So in order to write a program, I have to learn the ins and outs of how this library—supposedly just a command-line parser library—works. I need to know things like: Does it run commands in parallel? What is the global state it sets up before running my code? How does it do error handling? If I return `EXIT_FAILURE` from a command function, will that be the end of it, or will the library then take it upon itself to print an error message? Will the universe explode if I throw an exception?

As a programmer, and engineer, I *cannot* hand over responsibility for executing my code to an unknown, third-party entity. I need to have control over what gets executed, when, and how, or at least clear information and strong guarantees. I mean, you could *conceivably* write clear and complete enough documentation that I could trust your library enough to hand over control of my code to… but what you got sure ain’t it.

Not to mention, I don’t think you’ve even *touched* the tip of the iceberg of what your library *could* do, given a tree-like structure parsed out of the command line. Consider, for example, a command line utility that can run multiple commands:

```
./rats --database /path/to/rats.db sell Ryan 12400 buy Steve 9000 view Steve -l forest --label 'Steve in forest'
```

… which parses to the tree:

```
command{"./rats"}
  ├ option<path>{"database", "/path/to/rats.db"}
  ├ command{"sell"}
  │ ├ argument<string>{"name", "Ryan"}
  │ └ argument<double>{"price", 12400}
  ├ command{"buy"}
  │ ├ argument<string>{"name", "Steve"}
  │ └ argument<double>{"price", 9000}
  └ command{"view"}
    ├ argument<string>{"name", "Steve"}
    ├ option<rat_location>{"location", rat_location::forest}
    └ option<string>{"label", "Steve in forest"}
```

… which I could then scan and observe that of the three commands, the first two can be run in parallel.

Or consider a utility like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/), where the command line is actually a sequence of commands to load, create, modify, and/or save one or more images. That could be very easily represented as a tree, and there, too, it is possible that some of the commands could be run in parallel, or perhaps the program could detect when some temporary image is no longer necessary and free up resources early, or… I mean, the possibilities are endless.

But not if the library takes that kind of control away from the programmer. (Or, at *best*, things *may* be possible, but now your whole program would have to be written basically as a module to the (allegedly) command-line parser.)

As I said, the actual *parsing* part is fine, and parsing the command line as a tree is absolutely brilliant. If the library could content itself with just doing *that*, and giving me that tree, it would be perfect, and I could absolutely see myself using it. But because the library oversteps its bounds and actually *runs the entire program*… it’s a hard no, a complete non-starter.

My recommendation: Drop the “and execute” part. Or at least, split it out. Just parse the command-line, return the parsed tree, and you’re done. A command-line parser library should parse the command-line, and no more. A command-line parser library that parses the command-line and then also steals control of my program away from me? No thank you.

The second major problem with this library is: terminology confusion.

I would expect a command-line parsing library to use the terminology associated with command lines correctly. Or, at the very least, consistently. Instead, this library is all over the map. It uses the terms “option”, “parameter”, “flag”, “argument”, “command”, and various cognates in idiosyncratic ways, never clearly defining anything, and sometimes even switching them to make things even more confusing.

For example, you use the term “flag” to mean, basically, “anything that begins with a dash”. That means both options with a value like `--option value` and options without a value like `--option`. You call the latter “pure flags”. And to make things even more confusing, you also talk about “implicit value flags”… which are apparently also “pure flags”, except when they’re not because they have an explicit `bool` value (which can be “true” or “false”, but also, bizarrely, any random positive integer… which is *definitely* not going to cause problems or confusion (sarcasm)).

Well, the word “flag” actually has a meaning: [it means a boolean value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(programming)). In other words, `--option` is a flag. `--option value` is not. (Yes, even when `value` is a boolean value. In that case, it might be an option that is *setting* (or controlling) a flag, but not, itself, a flag.)

You also talk about “verbose flags”. To the rest of the universe, a verbose flag is a flag that affects the verbosity of a program (usually `-v` or `--verbose`). What you call “verbose flags” are normally called “long options”.

The terminology associated with command lines isn’t formally specified, but it is nevertheless pretty universal. Here are how two major command-line parsing libraries I have used, plus the POSIX standard, define things. I deliberately picked a mix including a C++ library (`Boost.Program_options`), a non-C++ library (`argparse`), and two different standards (GNU and POSIX). (The GNU standard also jibes with the terminology used by `getopt` et al.)

Given `prog -f --flag -o val --option value arg`

- [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

  - `-f`: option (and “… historically, "flags"”)
  - `--flag`: (not described)
  - `-o val`: option

    - `-o`: option
    - `val`: option-argument
  - `--option value`: (not described)
  - `arg`: operand
- [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html)

  - `-f`: option
  - `--flag`: long option
  - `-o val`: option

    - `-o`: option
    - `val`: option argument
  - `--option value`: (long) option

    - `--option`: (long) option
    - `value`: option argument
  - `arg`: argument
- [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

  - `-f`: flag
  - `--flag`: flag
  - `-o val`: option

    - `-o`: option name
    - `val`: option value
  - `--option value`: option

    - `--option`: option name
    - `value`: option value
  - `arg`: positional argument
- [`Boost.Program_options`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/program_options.html)

  - `-f`: option
  - `--flag`: option
  - `-o val`: option

    - `-o`: option name
    - `val`: option value
  - `--option value`: option

    - `--option`: option name
    - `value`: option value
  - `arg`: positional option

You should also look into [the distinction between “arguments” and “parameters”](https://eng.libretexts.org/Courses/Delta_College/C___Programming_I_(McClanahan)/10%3A_Functions/10.03%3A_Arguments_vs_Parameters).

Being cavalier with the terminology makes your library harder to understand, and probably doesn’t help with the design either. Having a clear understanding of what you are modelling is essential to making a good model, and clear and consistent terminology is step 1.

Finally, a couple of suggestions for important features that are lacking:

1. Parsing options files.

   This doesn’t need to mean parsing *structured* configuration files like INI or YAML or whatever. Simply the ability to read a file of command-line arguments would be good enough. Sometimes the command line simply isn’t enough, and sometimes you want to save a set of options for reuse.
2. Merging options sets.

   I frequently write programs that try to read configuration from default locations before the command line—for example, first from `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` then from every path `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`, all suffixed with a program-specific sub-path, then finally the command-line arguments take precedence. There should be a way to take the options loaded from one source, and merge them with the options from another source, with one of those sources taking precedence when options are duplicated (or, perhaps, a way to raise an error when certain options are duplicated).
3. More control flexibility with options.

   Sometimes options/parameters are required, sometimes they are optional. (Take the `cat` command, for example. It has an optional parameter: the file to read. If not given, it reads from `stdin`.) Sometimes options/parameters can appear multiple times. (Again, `cat`. It can take anywhere from zero to ∞ parameters.) It would be nice to be able to specify minimum/maximum times an option/parameter can appear. Also, sometimes options are mutually exclusive; it would be nice if that, too, could be supported.
4. Response files

   A fairly common feature of command-line argument libraries is response files. These are simply lists of command-line arguments (see point 1), usually specified with an `@`. So you could write `./prog @args.txt`, and it will read the file `args.txt` and use its contents as command-line arguments.

### Code review

```
#pragma once
```

[Don’t use `#pragma once`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf8-use-include-guards-for-all-header-files). It is non-standard, and for a very good reason.

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <format>
#include <any>
#include <map>
```

You are missing quite a few necessary includes. Without even scrolling, I see: `std::numeric_limits`, which requires `<limits>`; and `std::string`, which requires `<string>`.

```
#define PARAMETRIC_TABLE_WIDTH 60
```

There is no reason for this to be a macro. It should, at least, be an `inline` `constexpr` constant.

But I question whether this should be a constant at all. It should be both detected at run-time—because not every terminal will be 60 characters wide—and controllable by the user.

```
namespace parametric {
    constexpr inline int ERROR_RESULT = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

I am really not a fan of indenting at the namespace level. In practice, *all* of your code will be in a namespace, so if you indent at the namespace level, you automatically lose 4 characters of horizontal space. What a waste.

And it will only get worse if a library gets more complex. For example, are you going to waste *16 horizontal spaces* for code in:

```
namespace goubermouche {
inline namespace v1 {
namespace parametric {
namespace detail {
```

You’re already wasting half that just for what you’ve got.

```
    constexpr inline int ERROR_RESULT = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

[Don’t use `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for anything that is not a pre-processor macro](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl9-use-all_caps-for-macro-names-only).

But I would suggest this constant shouldn’t exist at all. Using error codes as return values is an anti-pattern.

```
    template<typename type>
    struct options_parser {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> type {
            return value;
        }
    };
```

So, this is the primary template for all options parsers, which means it is the template that is going to be used for all types that don’t have an option parser explicitly defined.

The first problem is that it will only work for types that are implicitly convertible from `std::string`.

The second problem is that it will work for *any* type that is implicitly convertible from `std::string`.

Both these problems stem from the same root: There is no sensible default for parsing types as command-line options. Simply converting from a string is not a good idea, because there are definitely going to be types that can be constructed from strings, but not in a way that makes sense as command-line arguments.

Rather than having a default parser that does something simplistic (which may not work for all types, and even when it does, may be wrong), it makes more sense to *not* have a default parser, and to only opt-in to parsing for types that it makes sense to. In other words, the primary template should be undefined.

There is currently [a proposal for a standard parsing facility](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p1729r3.html), which may be called `std::scan`. *That* would make sense for a default parser. So you’d have:

```
// Primary template: not defined.
template <typename>
struct options_parser;

template <std::scannable T>
struct options_parser
{
    static auto parse(std::string const& value) -> T
    {
        return std::scan<T>(value, "{}")->value();
    }
};
```

Note that the primary template is still undefined here.

Using current technology, you *could* have a default parser using IOstreams:

```
// Primary template: not defined.
template <typename>
struct options_parser;

template <typename T>
    requires requires { std::declval<std::istringstream&>() >> std::declval<T&>(); }
        and std::default_initializable<T>
struct options_parser
{
    static auto parse(std::string const& value) -> T
    {
        auto iss = std::istringstream{value};
        iss.imbue(std::locale::classic());

        auto t = T{};
        iss >> t;
        return t;
    }
};
```

But I would discourage that. It’s not a great default.

So, basically, I would suggest ditching the default implementation, and leaving the primary template undefined.

Another issue is error-handling. There is no documentation for how to handle errors in parsing… which is something that is notoriously error-prone.

Digging through the code, I discover that you can signal parse errors by throwing an exception… which is not great, but okay. *However*… the handler code uses `catch (...)`, which means it will be triggered by ***ANY*** exception; not just parse errors.

So imagine this situation: The user of a program offers a perfectly legit command line, with perfectly legit arguments… then gets an error message: “error: invalid format for positional argument 'number'”. What the flagnar? The argument is a number. I entered “69” (nice). How is “69” an invalid format for an integer?

What really happened is somewhere deep inside `std::stoi()`, the library attempted to do an allocation, but, oh no, out of memory, throw `std::bad_alloc`… which is caught by the `catch (...)` and interpreted as a parse error, even though it is no such thing.

Or consider this scenario. Imagine that the rats program has a feature where, in addition to a few default locations like “default” and “home”, it can load more viewing locations from a data file. However, I don’t know or care about that extra feature, the defaults are fine for me. So I run `rats view Jonathan -l default`… and get an error “error: invalid format for flag '-l'”… which has me scratching my head. What I don’t know… what I can’t know… is that the program is trying to load that extra locations database, but either not finding the file or the permissions are wrong or something.

The bottom line is this: Never assume anything about what you’ve caught in a `catch (...)` handler.

In particular, you shouldn’t be assuming that what you’ve caught is a parse error. It could be an out-of-memory error, or an error caused by something else entirely, in which case you should ignore it and pass it along… not swallow it and issue a misleading error message.

The *correct* thing to do here would be to have a dedicated parse error type, and only catch that and anything derived from it. Then an out-of-memory or file-not-found or permissions-error would pass through, be caught at `main()` (presumably), and the user would get a more useful message. Or at least, not an outright false one.

But even better… why deal with exceptions at all? Parse errors are not really all that exceptional. It would be better to return something like `std::expected`.

Also, you’re using C++20. There is no reason to use `std::string const&`. That requires constructing a string, just to parse it. You don’t need that. You can use `std::string_view`. Using strings for this is especially silly since you know you are parsing from `argv`, which is all `char` arrays; constructing strings out of those is superfluous.

```
    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<float> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> float {
            return std::stof(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<double> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> double {
            return std::stof(value);
        }
    };
```

First, I’m surprised this even compiles. You are already in namespace `parametric`. So `parametric::options_parser` within namespace `parametric` is `parametric::parametric::options_parser`.

Second, I could point out that you have forgotten `long double`. You’re also not taking into account the new fixed-width floating point types: `std::float32_t`, `std::bfloat16_t`, etc.. And you’re also not considering any extended floating point types.

Third, you have a bug: the parser for `double` uses `stof()`, which parses a `float`, meaning perfectly valid `double` values may be rejected.

Let’s solve the third problem by dealing with the second (and fix the first while we’re at it). Manually listing every floating point type is a sucker’s game. We have better tools:

```
template <std::floating_point T>
struct options_parser<T>
{
    static auto parse(std::string_view value) -> std::expected<T, /*???*/>
    {
        // ???
    }
};
```

This will automatically catch *every* floating point type, past and present, including all extended floating point types.

Now, to actually parse: The `sto???()` functions are hot garbage. First, they require a string. Second, they use the current C locale. Note: not the current C++ locale; the current C locale. Even if it *were* the C++ locale, that’s bad, because it would mean that the format for valid floating point numbers would depend on the user’s locale (maybe! locale-awareness is loads of fun!).

Again, we have better tools:

```
template <std::floating_point T>
struct options_parser<T>
{
    static auto parse(std::string_view value) -> std::expected<T, /*???*/>
    {
        auto const begin = value.data();
        auto const end = value.data() + value.size();

        auto result = T{};

        if (auto const [p, ec] = std::from_chars(begin, end, result); ec == std::errc{})
        {
            // Make sure everything was parsed:
            if (p != end)
                // return some error code

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            // return some error code
        }
    }
};
```

Now this will work for *every* floating point type, past and present, including extended floating point types, *and* with the most efficient parsing the standard offers.

```
    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<bool> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            if(value == "true") {
                return true;
            }

            if(value == "false") {
                return false;
            }

            return static_cast<bool>(std::stoul(value));
        }
    };
```

I question whether “true”/“false” make good defaults for a boolean option. What if the option is `--door`? “True”/“false” doesn’t make a lot of sense there; “open”/“closed” would. In other cases, maybe “on”/“off”.

But definitely, implicitly doing an integer conversion is a terrible idea. Maybe checking for “1”/“0” *might* make sense (though I don’t think so)… but a boolean option that *implicitly* accepts 12345 is broken, in my opinion. (Allowing *explicit* conversions from numbers is fine, though, but that isn’t relevant here.)

I would suggest not providing a default `bool` parser at all. And that means differentiating between options with values and options without (that is, flags). You have quite a bit of machinery to handle them both with a single type, which adds complexity in multiple places. I’d say forget all that, and have a type for options, and a type for flags.

```
    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint8_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint8_t {
            return static_cast<uint8_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint16_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint16_t {
            return static_cast<uint16_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint32_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint32_t {
            return std::stoul(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<uint64_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> uint64_t {
            return std::stoull(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int8_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int8_t {
            return static_cast<int8_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int16_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int16_t {
            return static_cast<int16_t>(std::stoi(value));
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int32_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int32_t {
            return std::stoi(value);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct parametric::options_parser<int64_t> {
        static auto parse(const std::string& value) -> int64_t {
            return std::stoll(value);
        }
    };
```

First, I have to point out that all of these are wrong, because all of them require `std::` before the type. There is no `int32_t`. It is `std::int32_t`. Most compilers, for historical reasons, will accept both… for now. That is likely to change very soon, with the coming of the `std` module.

Second, another important point is that all of those types are *optional*. In other words, not only is there no `int32_t`… there may not even be a `std::int32_t`. If you are going to use any of those types, you need to check for their existence.

And third, just as in the floating-point case, you haven’t accounted for all of the possibilities. Not only have you neglected any extended integer types (`std::int128_t`) and all the `std::int_fast??_t` and `std::int_least??_t` types, and even `std::size_t`… you haven’t even included `int`. (The fixed-size integer types *may* be aliases for the regular integer types… but the key word there is “*may*”.)

The solution here is basically the same as for the floating-point types:

```
template <std::integral T>
struct options_parser<T>
{
    static auto parse(std::string_view value) -> std::expected<T, /*???*/>
    {
        auto const begin = value.data();
        auto const end = value.data() + value.size();

        auto result = T{};

        if (auto const [p, ec] = std::from_chars(begin, end, result); ec == std::errc{})
        {
            // Make sure everything was parsed:
            if (p != end)
                // return some error code

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            // return some error code
        }
    }
};
```

But there’s a little hitch. `std::integral` includes `bool`, and the character types (`char`, `char8_t`, `wchar_t`, etc.), which we don’t want to include. So we need a new concept, but if we do that, we can combine both the integer and floating point parsers:

```
template <typename T>
concept character =
    std::same_as<T, char>
    or std::same_as<T, char8_t>
    or std::same_as<T, char16_t>
    or std::same_as<T, char32_t>
    or std::same_as<T, wchar_t>
;

template <typename T>
concept integer =
    std::integral<T>
    and (not character<T>)
    and (not std::same_as<T, bool>)
;

template <typename T>
concept number =
    std::floating_point<T>
    or integer<T>
;

// Parses any built in integer or floating-point type, including all
// extended types, with maximum efficiency.
template <number T>
struct options_parser<T>
{
    static auto parse(std::string_view value) -> std::expected<T, /*???*/>
    {
        auto const begin = value.data();
        auto const end = value.data() + value.size();

        auto result = T{};

        if (auto const [p, ec] = std::from_chars(begin, end, result); ec == std::errc{})
        {
            // Make sure everything was parsed:
            if (p != end)
                // return some error code

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            // return some error code
        }
    }
};
```

That will parse any built in integer or floating-point type, including all extended types, with maximum efficiency.

```
        inline auto is_help_flag(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            return value == "--help" || value == "-h";
        }
```

This should be `noexcept` and `constexpr`. (And, like most of the functions in the library, it should take a string view, not a string.)

```
        inline void print_aligned_strings(const std::vector<std::string>& strings, std::size_t start_offset, std::size_t max_width) {
            std::size_t current_width = 0;

            for (const auto& string : strings) {
                current_width += string.size();

                if (current_width > max_width) {
                    // print a newline and align to the beginning of the line above
                    std::cout << "\n" << std::string(start_offset, ' ');
                    current_width = string.size();
                }

                std::cout << string;
            }
        }
```

There is no need to create a vector of strings (extremely heavyweight!). All you need is a range of things that can be *viewed* as strings:

```
template <std::ranges::input_range Strings>
requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_value_t<Strings>, std::string_view>
constexpr auto print_aligned_strings(Strings&& strings, std::size_t start_offset, std::size_t max_width)
{
    // ...
}
```

The body of the function could be unchanged.

However, I should point out that constructing that string of spaces on each iteration of the loop is silly; you could construct it once before the loop, and just reuse it.

But you don’t even need that string at all. It would probably be more efficient to write spaces in a loop.

Also, you shouldn’t hard-code `std::cout`. That not only makes this function less flexible, it makes it *really* hard to test. (And you *are* testing your code, aren’t you?)

```
        inline auto is_verbose_flag(const std::string& value) -> bool {
            // NOTE: this isn't a smart function, but it handles everything correctly for
            //       our needs

            if (value.length() < 2) {
                return false;
            }

            return value[0] == '-' && value[1] == '-';
        }
```

All you need here is `return value.starts_with("--");`.

Same idea applies for `is_flag()`.

```
        template<typename key_type, typename value_type>
        class dual_map {
            using iterator = typename std::map<key_type, value_type>::iterator;
            using const_iterator = typename std::map<key_type, value_type>::const_iterator;
        public:
            auto insert(const key_type& primary_key, const value_type& value) -> value_type& {
                auto& val_ref = primary_map[primary_key];
                val_ref = value;
                return val_ref;
            }

            auto insert(const key_type& primary_key, const key_type& secondary_key, const value_type& value) -> value_type& {
                auto& val_ref = primary_map[primary_key];
                val_ref = value;
                secondary_to_primary_map[secondary_key] = primary_key;
                return val_ref;
            }

            auto begin() -> iterator { return primary_map.begin(); }
            auto end() -> iterator { return primary_map.end(); }

            auto begin() const -> const_iterator { return primary_map.begin(); }
            auto end() const -> const_iterator { return primary_map.end(); }

            auto cbegin() const -> const_iterator { return primary_map.cbegin(); }
            auto cend() const-> const_iterator { return primary_map.cend(); }

            auto find(const key_type& key) -> iterator {
                auto primary_it = primary_map.find(key);
                if (primary_it != primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_it;
                }

                auto secondary_it = secondary_to_primary_map.find(key);
                if (secondary_it != secondary_to_primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_map.find(secondary_it->second);
                }

                return end();
            }

            auto find(const key_type& key) const -> const_iterator {
                auto primary_it = primary_map.find(key);
                if (primary_it != primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_it;
                }

                auto secondary_it = secondary_to_primary_map.find(key);
                if (secondary_it != secondary_to_primary_map.end()) {
                    return primary_map.find(secondary_it->second);
                }

                return end();
            }

            auto empty() const -> bool {
                return primary_map.empty();
            }

            auto size() const -> std::size_t {
                return primary_map.size();
            }
        private:
            std::map<key_type, value_type> primary_map;
            std::unordered_map<key_type, key_type> secondary_to_primary_map;
        };
```

Okay, so burying this in the middle of an options parsing library is not wise. A multi-keyed map should be a library unto itself. This is *not* a trivial class (and your implementation is broken in many ways, but that’s probably not a problem for a detail class).

I would suggest that making a type like this should be an absolute last resort… something you shouldn’t even consider so long as there are any other conceivable options. And you do have other options. For example, instead of `dual_map<string, flag>`, you could do `std::unordered_map<string, std::shared_ptr<flag>>`, and map both `-o` and `--opt` to the same shared pointer.

However… the *correct* solution here, in my opinion, is not to use any kind of map at all. You are ultimately making a map of option/flag *names* to option/flag objects… but the option/flag objects *already know the names*. Both the long and short names. So you are duplicating information. You don’t want a map. You want a *set*. You want to make a hash for `flag`, and a key-equal function that transparently accepts strings, and will return `true` for both the short and long names. Most of the code that uses `m_flags` won’t even have to change (except for transforming a few `for (const auto& [name, flag] : m_flags)` to `for (const auto& flag : m_flags)`, and dropping a `.second` here and there).

```
        struct value_wrapper_interface {
            virtual auto parse(const std::string& value) -> std::any = 0;
            virtual ~value_wrapper_interface() = default;

            // used for cases when the value is implicit (ie. pure flags) 
            bool expects_value = true; 
        };

        template<typename type>
        struct value_wrapper : value_wrapper_interface {
            auto parse(const std::string& value) -> std::any override {
                return options_parser<type>::parse(value);
            }
        };

        using value_wrapper_ptr = std::shared_ptr<value_wrapper_interface>;
```

Without digging any, this all strikes me as *tragically* over-engineered. I see dynamic polymorphism, I see `std::any`, and I see type erasure via `std::shared_ptr`. To need all three of these things… that’s just insane. Typically you only need of the three, if any at all.

Again, without digging, just from the problem domain, I know that if you are building a tree of command-line argument data, that tree need only contain 3 or 4 different types:

1. Commands.
2. Options (with `std::any` values).
3. Flags.
4. Parameters.

So the command line:

```
rats.exe view Jonathan -l lhc --label Visit --smirk
```

… parses to:

```
command{"rats.exe"}
  └ command{"view"}
    ├ parameter<string>{"name", "Jonathan"}
    ├ option<rat_location>{"location", rat_location::lhc}
    ├ option<string>{"label", "Visit"}
    └ flag{"smirk"}
```

You don’t need anything more.

So the infinite open-endedness that dynamic polymorphism and type erasure offer are unnecessary. All you need is a `std::variant<command, option, flag, parameter>`, and you’re done. That will hold everything you could possibly want to hold. On construction, an `option` or `parameter` just needs to be given a function with the signature `auto f(string_view) -> std::any` (basically) that parses the string view as a `T`, and returns it an `any`. (And it would be nice if that function could be overridden, so I could parse the same type differently if I want.) Everything is already type-erased there.

Indeed, your entire tree could actually just be a root `command`, which holds a `std::vector<std::variant<command, option, flag, parameter>>` for sub-commands, options, etc..

```
    class parameters {
```

As far as I can tell, the only purpose of this class is to allow typing `output_parameters.get<T>("foo")` instead of `std::any_cast<T>(output_parameters.at("foo"))`. Indeed, the type even makes friends out of pretty much every other major class in the library so they can get at the actual map it supposedly wraps.

Actually this is an issue throughout the library: everything is friends with everything else. To call this a code smell is an understatement. At one point, you even have an abstract base class with a *protected* interface… and then you friend one of its *derived* classes… it’s a disaster. You’ve kinda defeated the whole purpose of access levels, classes, and encapsulation, and you might as well just make everything `public`. What all this friendliness signals is a spaghetti mess of responsibilities.

```
        context(int argc, char** argv) : arguments(argv, argv + argc) {
            arguments[0] = std::filesystem::path(argv[0]).filename().string();
        }
```

So, this constructor does two things, and I don’t think either of them make sense.

The first thing it does is transform the `argv` array into a `vector<string>`. But… *why*? Why create a vector to hold the arguments? They’re *already* in a perfectly serviceable array. Okay, you hate C arrays? Me, too. But in that case you have `std::span`. You don’t need a vector. That’s just duplicating the information, and doing an unnecessary allocation for the privilege.

You also don’t need strings. The data is already there in memory. Granted, it’s in C strings, but we have `std::string_view` for that. So, if anything, `arguments` should be a `std::span<std::string_view>`.

The second thing the constructor does is modify `argv[0]`. Again… *why*? The command `foo/bar` is *not* the same as the command `bar`. Why would would you modify the command to hide that information? When an application is properly installed, it is usually called without a path in any case—if the `bar` app were installed, then it would usually be invoked as just `bar`. Just about the only times it won’t be are during development or when the app isn’t properly installed… in which case, you shouldn’t *expect* a simple path-less command… or when the app *is* installed, but conflicts with another app with the same name… in which case, the path is vital information.

(Also, it bears mention that `argv[0]` isn’t necessarily going to be a path. So attempting to parse it as one could trigger chaos. The `path` constructor may throw, or the modification may mutilate the command in bizarre ways.)

This is a decision that a library should not be making behind the back of the user. What you could do is give the user the option of offering something to be used *instead* of `argv[0]`, but otherwise `argv[0]` should be left unmodified.

```
    class flag {
```

The short flag will always be a single character (or nothing), right? So is there a need to store it in a string?

Also, I’m not keen on the fact that the library uses the same classes for the options/flags/parameters/commands, and *descriptions* of the options/flags/parameters/commands. The reason is that *describing* an option/flag/parameter/command requires so much more information than the thing itself.

Take flags for example. The only data that needs to be stored in a flag is the name(s) of the flag. But the *description* of the flag needs the name(s), the description, the number of times it can appear, and probably other stuff. The description in particular probably requires an expensive allocated string, and it doesn’t need to be kept around after the parsing is done.

So consider that when I’m *describing* the flag, I would create a “flag description” object with all that information. Then the parsing happens, and the return value only includes the actual flag object. The description is thrown away, freeing up those resources.

This will be particularly important if you allow multiples of options/flags/parameters/commands. Suppose your program takes a list of files as positional parameters, and I give a command line with dozens or hundreds of files. It only needs a single “parameter description” object with the parameter name, description, min/max number of appearances, parse function, etc. to *describe* all those parameters for the sake of parsing. But when the command line is actually parsed, it produces dozens or hundreds of parameter objects. If the description were duplicated in all of those objects, that would be a massive waste.

If you look at `Boost.Program_options`, it builds up the entire set of option and parameter descriptions first in an `options_description` object… and then it uses that options description to parse multiple sources, and store the results in a `variables_map` (which, very basically, is just a `map<string, any>`). Python’s `argparse` does the same thing, basically. You build up the entire set of option and paramter descriptions in a `ArgumentParser` object… then use that with `.parse_args()` and store the results in a `Namespace` object. (I don’t think `argparse` has *built-in* support for multiple sources, but it’s pretty trivial to run the parser’s parse function on multiple sources, and then merge the results.) In both cases, all the options description information is left behind after parsing, because it is no longer necessary.

```
    class command_base {
```

So, this whole hierarchy is a complete mess.

To start: [protected data is a code smell](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c133-avoid-protected-data).

In fact, in general, [abstract base classes should have no data members](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i25-prefer-empty-abstract-classes-as-interfaces-to-class-hierarchies). If `command_base` is meant to define an interface, then [it should be pure abstract](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c121-if-a-base-class-is-used-as-an-interface-make-it-a-pure-abstract-class), and [it should not have any constructors](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c126-an-abstract-class-typically-doesnt-need-a-user-written-constructor). (It should also not be copyable or movable, but that’s a whole other set of issues.)

However… *is* it an interface? Because while it does declare pure virtual functions, they are all *protected*. Which is… weird. But it sorta kinda *is* an interface, but only to `command_group`… which is *derived* from `command_base`… but `command` which is also derived from `command_base` not only doesn’t use the interface, it makes the interface functions *private*… … … it’s a total mess.

The ugliest wart of this hierarchy has to be the `command_group` class. I get wanting to be able to group commands and options, but that is something that should only apply to *describing* options/flags/parameters/commands… not the actual option/flag/parameter/command data. (This is yet another reason why option/flag/parameter/command *description* data should be separate from option/flag/parameter/command data.)

And for the clearest illustration of how the `command_group` breaks the entire abstraction… let me ask a simple question. So, if I use this library in a simple program, like the very first, basic rats example, it comes with support for `-h`/`--help` built in, right? So `rats --help` just works. Great! Now, riddle me this. What if I want to support the very common `--version` option, to allow `rats --version` to print version and legal information for the program? How would I do that?

It turns out that `.add_flag()` is a member function of `command`… not `command_group` (and, by extension, `program`). The same is true for `.add_positional_argument()`. So what I have here is a library for describing program options and parameters… that doesn’t actually allow me to describe program options and parameters. Oh, I can describe program *sub-commands*, and then give *those* options and parameters. But I can’t add options or parameters to the program itself.

Now, the obvious fix here would be to add `.add_flag()` to `command_group`… except that `command_group` *shouldn’t* have options. That just doesn’t make sense. Each command should have options and parameters, but a *group* of commands shouldn’t (for the same logical reason that each *person* in a group of people should have a name and age, but the group itself should not).

So the next obvious fix would be to derive `program` from `command` instead of `command_group`… except now you can’t add sub-commands *or* groups of sub-commands, because `.add_command()` and `.add_command_group()` are both members of `command_group`, not `command`.

I would suggest binning the entire hierarchy, and starting from scratch, and this time, do not use the `friend` or `protected` keywords anywhere, at all. (In fact, I’d suggest going through the entire library, and removing all uses of `protected` and `friend`. They are not inherently evil, but you are using them as a crutch, and the library design is suffering because of it.) Start simple, with the most basic and necessary features first, and add complexity later. And think *very carefully* about the model, the structure, and the abstraction. (For example, very clearly, a program is not a command group. If anything it is a command. The only thing that makes it a “special” command is that its name is set by the command line, rather than specified… though you could allow overriding it. Other than that, the only other “special” thing about it is that it would be the root of your tree… but it could still just be a command like any other that happens to be the root.) And avoid artificial structure like `command_base` (which serves no purpose but to make `command_group` and `command` appear similar, even though they do not actually share an interface (because what interface there is hidden via `protected`)).

That’s it for the review. Hope it helps!

Comment: *"I see type erasure via `std::shared_ptr`"* The type erasure is done via the virtual base classes and `std::any`, but not `std::shared_ptr`: the latter doesn't erase types at all, it's only involvement is because you need some way to do heap allocations for derived objects if you want to store them in a container or build a tree out of them.

Comment: @indi Firstly, I have to thank you a **ton** for your code review, as it helped me immensely. I've originally developed parametric in a couple hours, because I needed a parameter parser which did what I needed at the time, hence why its so messy. I was, though, interested in what other people thought of the idea (tree structure etc.) and if they had any suggestions, hence why I posted it here. I'll rewrite the entire thing from scratch (although still with the tree structure) and with your suggestions in the coming month. I especially appreciate your notes on the parsing and concepts bits.